# Question about asymptotic analysis comparing two functions

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, asymptotics

I'd be glad for an explanation on the analysis of this exercise. Given these functions: $$f(n) = n^2 \\ g(n) = n^{2/3}$$

Show that $f(n) = O(g(n))$, or $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$ and comment if $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$

In my answer, it is $\Theta(g(n))$ with $n_0 = 1, C = 1$

**PS:** The exercise requires a mathematical demonstration of the answer.

Comment: It looks incorrect. can you please add more details as to how you got this answer?

Comment: For instance: $n^{1/2} \leq C * n^{2/3} => \frac{n^{1/2}}{n^{2/3}} \leq C$. If we replace the variables with $1$, the assumption is satisfied.

Comment: Same goes to $\Omega$

Comment: Please recheck the definitions of $\Omega, \Theta, O$ especially about the condition of n’s that you have to choose.

Comment: $\Omega$ means that there is a function multiplied by a constant that is $\leq$ than $f(n)$ for an existing $n_0, C$. $O$ is the upper bound and $\Theta$ means that there is both boundaries.

Comment: Could you please give more details about what's wrong so i can rethink the answer?

Comment: You are missing the key condition that n can grow arbitrarily large. Check the definitions here given in comparing orders of growth section. https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2013sp/supplemental/lectures/lec19-asymp/review.html

Comment: Sorry, i must have said that we need to demonstrate mathematically. That's where i'm struggling. I edited the question adding this information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104714/discussion-between-joann2555-and-apoorv-ingle).

Comment: In the original you use $n^2$ and $n^{2/3}$. In your first comment you appear to be using $n^{1/2}$ and $n^{2/3}$.

Comment: @RickDecker yes, sorry. I edited the question.